# Xcode Freezing on Mojave VirtualBox

Tags: xcode, macos, windows-10, virtualbox, macos-mojave

Setting up a Mac development build system on Windows using VirtualBox and Mojave. I got everything installed correctly, and it’s basically functioning fine, but whenever I try to build a project or do anything memory intensive in Xcode, it just freezes and beachballs. I never get any error messages or anything, and it does it on different types of projects. I have 8GB of RAM allocated, so I think that should be sufficient. Anyone running to this issue? Thanks!

Host: Windows 10 
Guest: macOS Mojave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to a High Sierra VM and it’s working alright now, guess the Mojave VM isn’t as stable or something.